# No puedo cargar imágenes desde la carpeta "static/img" del template "lineman-angular-template"

Tags: html, angularjs, css

Estoy utilizando el siguiente template con lineman: https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman-angular-template

Agregue una imagen a la carpeta "/static/img" y trato de cargarla desde login.html asi: `<img src="../static/img/min.png" />`

pero no carga la imagen...

Esta es la arquitectura de como esta definido el proyecto:

[image: Arquitectura]

Comment: Hola Marck Vit. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Al parecer en tu pregunta olvidaste especificar como cargas la imagen. Edita la pregunta y agrega la información relevante para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @devconcept estaba invisible por que el código no fue marcado como codigo.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas escribiendo mal la url. En lugar de

```
<img src="../static/img/min.png" />
```

debería ser

```
<img src="/img/min.png" />
```

o

```
<img src="img/min.png" />
```

La razón es que la plantilla automáticamente publica **todo el contenido** de la carpeta `static` como recursos estáticos pero la carpeta en si no se incluye ya que solo sirve de referencia.

Chequea la ayuda de la carpeta `static` en la estructura de [lineman](http://www.linemanjs.com/#directory-structure) y verás que dice

> otros ficheros estáticos que deban colocarse en una ruta relativa a `/`

También ten en cuenta que tienes un conflicto con el nombre de las carpetas. Renombra una de ellas y te debería funcionar

[image: conflicto]

Comment: Ya probé así como mencionas y tampoco, esa forma funciona para las imágenes que están en la carpeta "app/img".

Ya encontré como cargar la imagen pero no para este proyecto, si no para otro que utiliza el mismo template (tiene otra arquitectura) y fue así:

\img\carpeta\common\static\img\min.png donde "carpeta" esta al mismo nivel de "app" y de "config".

Gracias por responder @devconcept

Comment: @MarckVit Ten en cuenta que la app te está sirviendo una carpeta llamada `img` y dentro de tu carpeta `static` tambien tienes otra carpeta `img`. Esto te creará un conflicto. Prueba a renombrar la que está dentro de `static` y actualiza la url de tu imagen. Así debería funcionarte.

Comment: Funciono así como mencionas "Prueba a renombrar la que está dentro de static".

Gracias de nuevo @devconcept .

Comment: @MarckVit No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada si la consideraste útil.